# Countdown on modal

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Header, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { setInterval } from 'timers';

export default class LogoutModal extends Component {
  state = { timer};
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.today(), 1000);
  }

  today() {
    this.setState({
      timer:this.state.timer - 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        open={this.props.handleOpen}
        onClose={this.props.handleClose}
        basic
        size="small"
      >
        <Header icon="browser" content="Cookies policy" />
        <Modal.Content>Time left is: {this.state.timer}</Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button color="green" onClick={this.props.handleClose} inverted>
            <Icon name="checkmark" /> Got it
          </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to display a countdown on the semantinc ui modal but it only shows the timer inital value of 5. Please what could be wrong
I am trying to display a countdown on the semantinc ui modal but it only shows the timer inital value of 5. Please what could be wrong

Comment: What is the default value of timer state?

Comment: @OmiD initial state of timer is 5

Comment: @Chris I did but it still didn't work

Comment: Are you sure the initial timer is 5? Doesn't seem to be from the code you provided.

Comment: @AwudiEricOkyere are you getting any console errors ?

Comment: yes i do get some errors. i think the issue is with the semantic ui modal. It is unable to re-render the state

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what package 'timer' is, however, I would suggest putting your interval into its own variable inside CDM if that doesn't work, you should try with a vanilla setInterval. something along the lines of this:

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {
  this.setState({
    timer:this.state.timer - 1
  });
}, 1000);
```

Also, do not forget in handleClose and componentWillUnmount to clear your interval.

```
clearInterval(this.timer);
```

Comment: Thanks...the problem was from the timer module in which i imported the setInterval from. Thanks to all